# Linux sloppy mount

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, automounting

Could anyone describe to me what sloppy mount is? There's two mount points on my server but I have no idea how to erase the sloppy one. I hope some one could explain to me the potential faults or what's happening under the hood.

```
ILTLVLSSC418:/etc # mount
nfsserver:/export/sapmnt/T10 on /sapmnt/T10 type nfs (rw,soft,retrans=2,addr=10.96.88.7)
nfsserver:/export/saptrans/trans1 on /usr/sap/trans type nfs (rw,soft,retrans=2,addr=10.96.88.7)
nfsserver:/export/sapmnt/T10 on /sapmnt/T10 type nfs(rw,nfsvers=3,soft,retrans=2,sloppy,addr=10.96.88.7)
nfsserver:/export/saptrans/trans1 on /usr/sap/trans type nfs4 (rw,soft,retrans=2,sloppy,addr=10.96.88.7,clientaddr=10.26.91.11)
```

The "mount" command result is shown above.

Plus I could not execute "umount", as it would fail and remount back.

Answer (score 6):

The `sloppy` means that the underlying mount system should ignore options it doesn't understand, instead of failing to mount altogether. This is usually used in combination with NFS automount, which leads to the second issue: the automatic remounting.

`automount` is used to automatically mount a filesystem when it is needed, instead of having it mounted all the time; again usually used with NFS. Simply doing a `ls -l` of the mountpoint is enough... To remove these, check `/etc/auto.*` files, start with `auto.master` which may link to other files. After changing those files you need to reload `autofs`.

Comment: I finally figure out the issue which is answered below, thanks for your sincere answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

yesterday I finally figure out the solution to the issue, by removing the according contents in `/etc/fstab`.

Well, for the reason why, that's because the `/etc/fstab` function the same as the `/etc/auto.*`, which is pointed to by `auto.master`. Duplicated mount appears because of the co-existence of the according contents in the two files.

Comment: Could you show the entry in `/etc/fstab` that you removed?